# Sobrepor o método preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

Existe alguma maneira de "desfazer" o método `preventDefault()`?
Tenho este pequeno código que me resolve isto, mas queria saber se há alguma maneira mais eficiente de o fazer.

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.data('working', false);
$form.data('canSubmit', false);

$form.submit(function (e) {
    if (form.validations.form($form)) {
        if (!$form.data('working')) {
            $form.data('working', true);

            if ($form.data('canSubmit')) {
                // make the post here
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get(BASE + 'file.txt', function (response) {
                    var lastPartnerSent = response;
                    var nextPartner = '';
                    switch (lastEmailSent) {
                        case 'Empresa 1':
                            nextPartner = 'Empresa 2';
                            break;
                        case 'Empresa 2':
                            nextPartner = 'Empresa 3';
                            break;
                        default:
                            nextPartner = 'Empresa 1';
                    }

                    $('input.i_parceiro').val(nextPartner);
                    $form.data('canSubmit', true);
                    $form.submit();
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        $form.data('working', false);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Isto acontece pois tenho de ler e escrever num ficheiro depois de fazer as validações dos campos e só depois disso fazer o post para a página.
O post não pode ser feito por ajax.

A pergunta é basicamente se é possível dividir por 3 passos aquele formulário, ie:

1º validar campos, por exemplo nome, email, etc (síncrono)

2º consoante os dados já validados, fazer um ajax que me irá acrescentar um campo "parceiro" ao formulário (assíncrono)

3º submeter o formulário por post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `.on()` e `.off()`, ou seja adicionar o observador de eventos e depois retirar caso a validação dê `true`.

A ideia seria assim (repara que é pseudo-código para dar uma ideia de como fazer):

```
$form.on('submit', verificador);

function verificador(e){
    if (!validouCerto) return e.preventDefault(); // ou outros avisos caso não valide

    // aqui código caso valide (pois o "if" anterior faria "return" caso não valide)
    $form.off('submit', verificador);
    $form.submit();
}
```

A razão de usar `$form.on('submit', verificador);` é para podermos usar o `.off()` que tem de indicar a mesma função para ela poder ser retirada.

Depois das informações que juntaste na pergunta/chat e comments sugiro que uses assim:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.on('submit', verificador);

function verificador(e) {
    var validou = form.validations.form($form);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!validou) return false;

    $.get(BASE + 'file.txt', function (response) {
        var lastPartnerSent = response;
        var nextPartner = '';
        switch (lastEmailSent) {
            case 'Empresa 1':
                nextPartner = 'Empresa 2';
                break;
            case 'Empresa 2':
                nextPartner = 'Empresa 3';
                break;
            default:
                nextPartner = 'Empresa 1';
        }

        $('input.i_parceiro').val(nextPartner);
        $form.off('submit', verificador);
        $form.submit();
    });
}
```